# How does a duel work in the game BANG?

Tags: bang

Not sure how a duel works in the game BANG! If both the person playing the duel card has a single bang card, and the person they challenge has a single bang card - is it a draw? 
Or does the person playing the duel card have the advantage of going second - meaning when the person they challenge runs out of bang cards - they win without having to put down a bang card? Like can they win without throwing down a bang card?
Or does it work like an actual gun duel works - where each player has to throw down bang cards head to head until someone runs out?
Can there be a "draw" if both players have the same number of bang cards?  Or is the challenged player always disadvantaged...?

Answer (score 4):

A duel is a special attack that must be responded to by discarding a bang. If the person the duel is played on is unable to discard a bang they take a hit. If they are able to it goes back to the person who played the duel. If they can't discard a bang they take a hit however if they can the process repeats by going back and forth between the players until one of them is no longer able to discard a bang and that player takes a hit.

Duel

> With this card you can challenge any other
>   player (staring him in the eyes!), regardless
>   of the distance. The challenged player may discard a BANG!
>   card (even though it is not his turn!). If he does, you may
>   discard a BANG! card, and so on: the first player failing to
>   discard a BANG! card loses one life point, and the duel is
>   over. You cannot play Missed! or use the Barrel during a
>   duel. The Duel is not a BANG! card. BANG! cards discarded
>   during a Duel are not accounted towards the “one BANG!
>   card” limitation.

Comment: OK thanks Joe.  We were arguing because if the player that it is played on doesn't have ANY bangs, the player that played the duel card technically doesn't have to have a bang card either to win the duel.  That didn't seem fair in the spirit of an actual duel.  I think a couple of us had the concept of playing "war" with a deck of cards in mind...with both players throwing down head to head.

Comment: Think of the duel card as the first bang that starts it off and if the player doesn't have any bangs in their hand they are just risking it.